# How to tell whether an update statement is successful in pysqlite 2.6.3

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I'm using `pysqlite` to talk to a SQLite db, and I wonder what is the right way to check whether an `UPDATE` SQL statement has actually successfully update something in a table.

Is there a variable I can quickly check after the execution for this in `pysqlite`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the `cursor.rowcount` attribute; it'll indicate the number of affected rows.

If an `UPDATE` was not successful the `rowcount` will be 0:

```
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar, baz)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1042ab6c0>
>>> conn.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1042ab730>
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('UPDATE foo SET baz=3 WHERE bar=2')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1042ab6c0>
>>> cursor.rowcount
0
>>> cursor.execute('UPDATE foo SET baz=3 WHERE bar=1')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x1042ab6c0>
>>> cursor.rowcount
1
```

Of course, if you try to update a table or column that doesn't exist, an exception is thrown instead:

```
>>> cursor.execute('UPDATE nonesuch SET baz=3 WHERE bar=2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: nonesuch
>>> cursor.execute('UPDATE foo SET nonesuchcolumn=3 WHERE bar=2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: nonesuchcolumn
```

I used the [`sqlite3` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) included with Python to demo this; `pysqlite2` was added to Python under that name in Python 2.5. The difference is merely the import:

```
try:
    import sqlite3  # included library
except ImportError:
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3  # use pysqlite2 instead
```

Comment: I would take unsuccesful to mean "failed" - rather than just didn't update anything...

Comment: Exactly what I mean - just because something doesn't affect any rows, doesn't mean it was unsuccessful :) It succeeded and didn't actually do anything!?

Comment: @JonClements: It's the OP asking for a variable that made me assume it was about non-matching rows, really. The exception is kinda obvious, I'd say.